# $lookup with two fields with same collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following **challenge** collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4ef87fdc816e25d5eea3de"),
    "receiver" : ObjectId("5b4c3000c851e3347d077312"),
    "receiverWorkoutId" : ObjectId("5b4ee663a769cb6459180dab"),
    "sender" : ObjectId("5b4c3432bad1c64f82fd4d94"),
}
```

I have following **user** collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4c3432bad1c64f82fd4d94"),
    "name": "bruce wayne"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4c3000c851e3347d077312"),
    "name": "clerk kent"
}
```

I need following Expexcted output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b4ef87fdc816e25d5eea3de"),
    "sender" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5b4c3432bad1c64f82fd4d94"),
      "name": "bruce wayne"
    },
    "receiverWorkoutId" : ObjectId("5b4ee663a769cb6459180dab"),
    "receiver" : {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5b4c3000c851e3347d077312"),
      "name": "clerk kent"
    }
}
```

I know I can do something like this with two `$lookup` stages but I want to do with single `$lookup` stage with `let` and `pipeline`

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation query in 3.6.

Use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator to match the sender and receiver values in the user collection followed by sort order with [`$indexOfArray`](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) to order the matches with sender first and receiver second.

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to replace the sender and receiver collection with referenced values.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with exclusion to drop the user collection field.

```
db.challenge.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"user",
    "let":{"sender":"$sender", "receiver":"$receiver"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$_id",["$$sender", "$$receiver"]]}}},
      {"$addFields":{ "sortorder":{"$indexOfArray":[["$$sender", "$$receiver"], "$_id"]}}}, 
      {"$sort":{"sortorder":1}}
    ]
    "as":"senderandreceiver"
  }},
 {"$addFields":{"sender":{"$arrayElemAt":["$senderandreceiver",0]}, "receiver":{"$arrayElemAt":["$senderandreceiver",1]}}},
 {"$project":{"senderandreceiver":0}},
])
```

Comment: Only this is the way to do this? Which is better doing lookup seprately for both or this? Because It doesn't seems to be a good way... ?

Comment: Not sure if this is the only way but I would have used two lookups. Newer lookups are best used when you have multiple join conditions. You can use mongoose populate for your use case.

Comment: Well after `$lookup`  I think populate is not a good approach for joining two collections... ***Newer lookups are best used when you have multiple join conditions*** how? because from above I cannot see a good way